Excel VBA Function only works when a cell in the table being referenced is selected
Function FILTERCRIT(rng As Range) As String

    Application.Volatile
    Dim Filter As String
    
    
    Set rng = Worksheets("HOUSING").ListObjects("Table4").ListColumns("HOUSING").Range
    
    Filter = "{All}"
    With rng.Parent.AutoFilter
        Set rng = Worksheets("HOUSING").ListObjects("Table4").ListColumns("HOUSING").Range
        If Intersect(rng, rng) Is Nothing Then GoTo Finish
        With .Filters(rng.Column - rng.Column + 1)
            If Not .On Then GoTo Finish
            Filter = .Criteria1
            Select Case .Operator
                Case xlAnd
                    Filter = Filter & " AND " & .Criteria2
                Case xlOr
                    Filter = Filter & " OR " & .Criteria2
            End Select
        End With
    End With
    
Finish:
  
    FILTERCRIT = Filter
  
End Function

When a filter criteria is selected the above code should output the selected criteria for reference in a formula. When a cell in the table being reference is selected the code works as intended and the cell with the formula "=FilterCrit(Table4[[#Headers],[HOUSING]])" updates as expected. However if another cell outside the table is selected the cell with the formula above outputs "#VALUE!".
Any idea why this is?

Note: your parameter is rng As Range, so why do you have Set rng = ... within the function?

If Intersect(rng, rng) Is Nothing also seems to be something which needs a fix.  rng will always intersect with itself

What is the intended purpose of the rng parameter in your function?
